# How to Filter a DropDownList from another DropDownList (SPDataSource + ControlParameter way)

Tags: sharepoint

I’m trying to connect two DropDownList (**ddlCountry and ddlCity**) together. I want that when the user changes the Country, the ddlCity is updated consequently.

To do it, I created two lists:

·         **Country (ID, Title)**

·         **City (ID, Title, Country)**  [Country is a lookup field]

Then I created an ASPX page with 2 DropDownList connected to Country and City through 2 SPDataSource (dsCountry and dsCity).

When I load my page, the City DropDownList is populated accordingly to the Country DropDownList, but when I change the Country, nothing happens and ddlCity shows null always 
This is my code:

```
<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true"    selectcommand="<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy></Query>" id="dsCountry">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ListName" DefaultValue="Country"/> 
    </SelectParameters>
</SharePoint:SPDataSource>

<p>Country: 
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlCountry" DataValueField="Title" DataTextField="Title" DataSourceID="dsCountry" AutoPostBack="True" />
</p>

<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" UseInternalName="true"    selectcommand="<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Country" /><Value Type="Lookup">{country}</Value></Eq></Where></Query>"    id="dsCity">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:parameter DefaultValue="City" Name="ListName"></asp:parameter>
        <asp:controlparameter name="country" controlid="ddlCountry" propertyname="SelectedValue"/>
    </SelectParameters>
</SharePoint:SPDataSource>
<p>City:  
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="ddlCity" DataValueField="Title" DataTextField="Title" DataSourceID="dsCity" />
</p>
```

**Please note:**

·         In ddlCountry AutoPostBack = True

·         In dsCity, in the CAML query there’s a parameter called “country”, connected to ddlCountry through a ControlParameter

I don’t understand why my filtering doesn’t work when I change the country… I can see the page reloading, but nothing happens… any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the variable be:

```
{$country}
```

Interested in knowing if you ever found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is serious thread necromancy, but in case you're still interested, or anyone else finds this through Google...

Try setting the `EnableViewState` attribute of the second (filtered) dropdown to `false`. This will force the control to get a new set of data (with the new filter) from the SPDataSource, instead of getting its previous set from before the post back from the View State.

Have a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spdatasource.selectparameters.aspx) for this specific example, and [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) for a more general overview of the View State and what it does.